# C# Generics on Fields

Tags: c#, generics, field

I have a dictionary `public readonly Dictionary<NetworkSide, PacketHandler<IPacketListener>> Handlers = new();`. `IPacketListener` can be of multiple types, like `IClientPacketListener` or `IServerPacketListener` (both extend `IPacketListener`). The issue is that I cannot add to the dictionary using the method below, because the compiler thinks that it's not possible to convert source type `PacketHandler<T>` to target type `PacketHandler<IPacketListener>`, even tho `T` extends `IPacketListener`. Any way to get around this?

```cs
public readonly Dictionary<NetworkSide, PacketHandler<IPacketListener>> Handlers = new();

public Add<T>(NetworkSide side, PacketHandler<T> handler) where T : IPacketListener {
    Handlers[side] = handler;    <<< Error
}
```

I have tried to generify the Dictionary using `public readonly <T> Dictionary<NetworkSide, PacketHandler<T>> where T : IPacketListener = new();`, but something like this is not allowed in C#.

For Java, this would be really easy to do using a wildcard `public Map<NetworkSide, PacketHandler<? extends PacketListener>> handlers = new ...;`

I know it must be possible somehow...

Comment: Don't use public fields to begin with. Only properties are part of an object's API. Fields are *always* implementation details, even if they're public. Serializers for example work with properties, not fields.

Comment: As for `compiler think`, the compiler is the final authority on what is and isn't allowed. In this case, the cast is wrong. Just because the type parameters inherit from one another doesn't mean the *generic types* inherit from one another. This is where [Covariance and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) come in, which only apply to interfaces, arrays and delegates. Not classes, like dictionaries

Comment: To solve the problem you'll have to use interfaces like `IDictionary<>` instead of `Dictionary` at the very least

Comment: Changing my Property to IDictionary does not change the fact that I cannot add a generic extending `IPacketListener` to a Dictionary of type `IPacketListener`

Comment: This means that `PacketHandler` isn't a delegate and needs to be replaced by an interface as well. What are you trying to do? There are probably better ways to do it

Comment: My PacketHandler is an instantiated class, so I cannot simply swap it out with an interface. The code registeres Packets for both Client and Server in different scenarios (Login, Auth,...) I have the full code for the NetworkState class in this pastebin:
C# Variant (not working): https://pastebin.com/Xi2anR0N
Java Variant (working + documentation): https://pastebin.com/3B3Rwnir

Comment: You'll have to use a different design then. Java probably works because it erases types at runtime. .NET doesn't. `I cannot simply swap it out with an interface` why not? As long as you remove the public fields, which you should anyway, you can add all the members you want to an interface. Properties aren't just getter/setter methods, they're part of a type's surface. Fields aren't

Comment: I fixed it by simply casting my generic parameter to the interface type... Thanks though for pointing me in the right direction, much appreciated =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by simply casting my generic parameter to the interface type...
`this._handlers[side] = (IPacketHandler<IPacketListener>) handler;`

Comment: This shouldn't work unless you have defined your interface correctly - and you haven't shown us that in the question. Please update the question to make this answer make sense.

Comment: well, as I said, I just needed to add a basic cast from `IPacketHandler<TPl>` to `IPacketHandler<IPacketListener>`. No need to vote me down because of that.

Comment: Yes, there is. Your question is incomplete and, therefore, this answer is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

There's a slight difference between using a T and incorporating an interface. Hope the below clarifies it for you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var handler = new PacketHandler();
        var impl = new PacketHandlerImplementation<PacketHandler>();
        
        Console.WriteLine("You're awesome");
    }
    
    public interface IPacketListener
    {
    }
    
    public class PacketHandler
        : IPacketListener
    {
            
    }
    
    public class PacketHandlerImplementation<T>
        where T : IPacketListener
    {
            
    }
    
    public class DictionaryTest
    {
        public readonly Dictionary<string, PacketHandlerImplementation<IPacketListener>> Handlers;

        public static void Add<T>(string side, PacketHandlerImplementation<T> handler) 
            where T : IPacketListener
        {
                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code already represents what I'm trying to do. The error keeps being on the line where I try to add the `handler` to the dictionary. 

`NetworkState.cs(37, 30): [CS0029] Cannot implicitly convert type 'NetworkState.PacketHandler<TPl>' to 'NetworkState.PacketHandler<IPacketListener>'`